# Call method from HTML only one time in Angular2

Tags: html, angular, web, optimization

I would like to implement img, with src depending on a variable in back.
so I have this :
`<img src="./image/-ex-{{getImg()}}.png" />`

But it calls the function of every screen event. I want that it load the picture at the begin and  then it never call the function again

my back :

```
`getImg() {
    return this.iso === '0' ? 'a' :
           this.iso === '1' ? 'b' :
           this.iso === '2' ? 'c' :'d';
  }`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just declare a variable, e.g. `private imgUrl: string;` then in your `ngOnInit()` or `constructor()` call `this.imgUrl = getImg()` and in your HTML `<img src="./image/-ex-{{imgUrl}}.png" />`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of src="./image/-ex-{{getImg()}}.png", src="./image/-ex-{{iso}}.png" and get the value of this.iso in the constructor or ngInit.

This will avoid calling the function multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

just use a boolean to verify the method is called before

```
`getImg() {
    if(this.calledBefore) {
      return;
    }
    this.calledBefore = true;
    return this.iso === '0' ? 'a' :
           this.iso === '1' ? 'b' :
           this.iso === '2' ? 'c' :'d';
  }
```

Or use a varible to store the image url in the component

```
constructor() {
   this.imageUrl = this.getImg();
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with dynamic data, the best approach would be to use a pipe. Here is an example

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
    
@Pipe({
  name: 'imgSrc'
})
export class ImgSrcPipe implements PipeTransform {
    
transform(value : any): string {
  return value === '0' ? 'a' :
         value === '1' ? 'b' :
         value === '2' ? 'c' :'d';
  }
    
}
```